# Can this Mysql query be amended to display invoice only once for the same idinvoice

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, aggregate

The query below

```
SELECT
<output name="c.name" title="Name" />,
<output name="c.reference" title="Reference No." />,
<output name="i.idinvoice" title="Invoice ID" />,
<output replace="(SUM(v.quantity * s.charges))/COUNT(i.idinvoice)" />As Invoice
<output replace="p.amount" />AS Amount,
<output replace="p.idpayment" title="Payment ID" />,
<output replace="p.cheque_no title="Cheque No" />,
<output replace="p.pdatetime" title="Processed Time" />,
<output replace="p.user" title="Processed By" type="user" attribute="username" />
FROM inv i
LEFT JOIN invitem v ON v.idinvoice = i.idinvoice
LEFT JOIN service s ON s.idservice = v.idservice
LEFT JOIN payment p ON p.idinvoice = i.idinvoice
LEFT JOIN address a ON a.idaddress = i.idaddress
LEFT JOIN client c ON c.idclient = a.idclient
WHERE a.idaddress = '<input name="idaddress" />'
GROUP BY i.idinvoice, p.amount, p.idpayment, p.cheque_no, p.pdatetime, p.user
ORDER BY i.idinvoice DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the idinvoice shown once, your GROUP BY should only include the IDINVOICE. You'll have to decide how to display the other parameters (SUM/AVG/random/none...).

```
SELECT
<output name="c.name" title="Name" />,
<output name="c.reference" title="Reference No." />,
<output replace="i.idinvoice" title="Invoice ID" />,
<output replace="(SUM(v.quantity * s.charges))/COUNT(i.idinvoice)" />AS Invoice,
<output replace="(p.amount)" data="float" />As Amount,
<output name="p.idpayment" title="Payment ID" />,
<output replace="p.cheque_no" title="Cheque No" />,
<output replace="p.pdatetime" title="Processed Time" />,
<output replace="p.user" title="Processed By" type="user" attribute="username" />
FROM inv i
LEFT JOIN invitem v ON v.idinvoice = i.idinvoice
LEFT JOIN service s ON s.idservice = v.idservice
LEFT JOIN payment p ON i.idinvoice = p.idinvoice
LEFT JOIN address a ON a.idaddress = i.idaddress
LEFT JOIN client c ON c.idclient = a.idclient
WHERE a.idaddress = '<input name="idaddress" />'
GROUP BY i.idinvoice
ORDER BY i.idinvoice DESC
```

Comment: Ok. So if you only want to display one line for invoiceID 295, what data would you want to put in the other columns? For example, in Amount?

Comment: If we can use IF idinvoice same as previous then no display for the next row, column Amount

Comment: That's more a GUI question than a MySQL question. Change your GUI to hide the value or merge the rows - depending on your GUI's capabilities.

Comment: Can I do this
"IF((idinvoice == idinvoice-1),'',(SUM(v.quantity * s.charges))/COUNT(i.idinvoice)" (though idinvoice-1 is not quite right, it should be previous idinvoice. If I can get the previous idinvoice expression, then this might work.

Comment: This snippet below uses the same GUI and makes the data visible if published. Going along the same line, I was thinking that it is possible to do the same if I can get the previous idinvoice expression.
replace="IF(published, a.idaddress,'')

Comment: I am sorry. You are right. It cannot be done using just Mysql